# ASP .NET Repeater Control containing LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, repeater, linkbutton

I am displaying a list of accounts objects in a repeater. Each object contains three fields namely studentID, studentName and studentAge. I have wrapped it with a [link button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx). As a result the each individual item which is displayed is clickable. I have also added a click handler to the link button. The problem is that how am I supposed to know which student was clicked? Because originally I want to navigate to the next page and display that particular student's details. Once I know which student is clicked then I can store his details in a session object and then navigate to the new page and get it back.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, it would be better to use a normal hyperlink, pass the ID as query string, and have the new page get the details.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" 
               NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("studentID", "StudentDetails.aspx?id={0}") %>'
               Text="Details" />
```

**Update:**

To get the studentID on the same page, use the [ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) event instead and have the `LinkButton` as follows:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server"
                CommandName="StudentDetails"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("studentID") %>' />
```

The studentID will be stored into the `CommandArgument` property, which value will be passed to the `ItemCommand` event handler.

Comment: No I cannot use hyperlink as on the next page I don't have access to the List of account objects. I need to extract the object on this page itself and then pass it through to the next page through session variable.

Comment: @VVV, I see. I thought you were going to load the record from the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
               NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"studentID", "StudentDetails.aspx?Id={0}") %>'
               Text="Details" />
```